# Formal proof that Cesaro limit of $x_n$ exists, but Cesaro limit of $f(x_n)$ does not

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> A problem and solution are given below. I was wondering how I'd formally prove that $\{x_n\}$ has C limit $c$ but that the averages of $\{f(x_n)\}$ oscillate?

It seems intuitive that the $x_n$'s tend to zero. For a formal proof, I'm looking for a standard $\epsilon$ proof. So for an arbitrary $\epsilon > 0,$ I need to find N large enough so that $|\dfrac{x_1+\cdots + x_n}n - c| < \epsilon$ for all $n\ge N$. If only a very small fraction of the $x_i$'s are a's and b's, one can make this quantity small and if the rest are c's the average should tend to $\epsilon$.

The question:

> If for a sequence $x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}, \cdots, \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(x_{1}+x_{2}+\cdots+x_{n}\right) / n$ exists, call this limit the $C$-limit of the sequence. A function $f(x)$ from $[0,1]$ to the reals is called a supercontinuous function on the interval $[0,1]$ if the $C$-limit exists for the sequence $f\left(x_{1}\right), f\left(x_{2}\right), f\left(x_{3}\right), \cdots$ whenever the $C$-limit exists for the sequence $x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3} \cdots$. Find all supercontinuous functions on $[0,1]$.

And the solution:

> A function is "supercontinuous" if and only if it is affine, $f(x)=A x+B$. The sufficiency is trivial (and was worth 1 point in the grading). For the necessity: First we note that it is not assumed that $f(C$-limit) $=C$-limit $(f)$ (otherwise the solution could be materially simplified). The essential steps are to show, that if $f$ is supercontinuous, then (1) $f$ is continuous, and (2) $f((a+b) / 2)=(f(a+f(b)) / 2$ for all $a, b$. These two statements imply that $f$ is affine. The proofs of (1) and (2) are similar; we give (2) (which is the harder). Set $c=(a+b) / 2$, and suppose $f(c) \neq(f(a)$ $+f(b)) / 2$. Imagine any sequence of integers $N_{i}$ which ' grows very rapidly'; say let $N_{i+1}$ exceed $2^{i} N^{i}$. Then construct a sequence of points $\left\{x_{n}\right\}$ as follows: Break the sequence into blocks, alternating between
> and
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> &\left\{x_{n}\right\}=a, b, a, b, a, b, \cdots \\
> &\left\{x_{n}\right\}=c, c, c, c, c, c, \cdots
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> the $a b$ pattern holding for $N_{2,-1} \leqq n<N_{2 i}$, and the $c$ pattern holding for $N_{2 i} \leqq n<N_{2 i+1}$. Then $\left\{x_{n}\right\}$ has the $C$ limit $c$, but the averages of $\left\{f\left(x_{n}\right)\right\}$ oscillate (because the lengths of the blocks $N_{i} \leqq n<N_{i+1}$ increase very fast, and $f(c) \neq$ the average of $f(a)$ and $f(b))$. Thus the $C$-limit of $\left\{f\left(x_{n}\right)\right\}$ does not exist, a contradiction.

transcribed from screenshots [one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OtDb.png) and [two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtgZE.jpg).

Comment: The key idea here is that the size of the blocks increase fast enough that by the end of each block, the overall average of the $f(x_n)$ is dominated by the average of the final block. The averages for $a,b$ blocks is $(f(a) + f(b))/2$. The average for the $c$ blocks is just $f(c)$, As these are different values, the C-sum must move back and forth between being near one of them at the end of one block, to being near the other at the end of the next block.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks, but I'm pretty sure that's exactly what they claimed in the solution. The point of this question is to obtain a formal proof of their claim for any such sequence of integers $N_i$.

Comment: Of course it is what they claimed in the solution. That is why I opened with the phrase "the key idea here", which indicates that I am not introducing anything new, but rather am attempting to clarify something already there. My point was to show how the idea is intuitive - just keep adding $a,b$ until the average is near $(f(a) + f(b))/2$, then keep adding $c$ until the average is near $f(c)$. Since you can always do both, it is possible to construct a sequence where the C-sum moves back and forth between them. This understanding makes the proof straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $\DeclareMathOperator*{\Clim}{C-lim}$ $\Clim_{n\to\infty} x_n = c$.

If $N(n,y)$ is the number of terms with index $i\le n$ and value $x_i=y$, then
$$A_n:=\left|\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n x_k - c\right| = \left|\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n (x_k - c)\right| = \frac1n|N(n,a)(a-c) + N(n,b)(b-c)| $$
By construction $|N(n,a) - N(n,b) |\le 1$. So
$$ A_n \le \frac{|a|+|b|+2|c|}n + \frac{2N(n,a)}n\underbrace{\Big|\frac{a+b}2 - c\Big|}_{=0} = \frac{|a|+|b|+2|c|}n \to 0.$$
Therefore
$$ \Clim_{n\to\infty} x_n = c.$$

2. Repeating the analogous computation for $f(x_n)$ will fail to show convergence.

In fact
$$  \frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n f(x_k) = f(c) + \frac{2N(n,a)}n\Big(\frac{f(a)+f(b)}2-f(c)\Big)+O(1/n)$$
and it is clear that if we choose the $N_i$s well, we can force $2N(n,a)/n$ to be arbitrarily close to two different constants, e.g. $1/3$ and $2/3$, at infinitely many $n$. Hence, $f(x_n)$ does not have a C-limit.

Details on the sequence - the biggest difference is before you begin adding terms from the abab sequence, and right after. In symbols, this amounts to (say $N_i$s are even for simplicity) $$2N(N_{2i},a)=\sum_{j=1}^i N_{2j}-N_{2j-1}=2N(N_{2i+1}-1,a).$$ The game is therefore to have different limiting values as $i\to \infty$ for
$$ X_i=\frac{\sum_{j=1}^i N_{2j}-N_{2j-1}}{N_{2i}} \qquad \text{and}\qquad Y_i=\frac{\sum_{j=1}^i N_{2j}-N_{2j-1}}{N_{2i+1}-1}.$$
This can be achieved with $N_i=2^i$:
\begin{align} X_i = \frac{\frac23(4^i-1)}{4^i} \to \frac23 \qquad \text{and}\qquad
 Y_i = \frac{\frac23(4^i-1)}{2\cdot 4^i-1}\to\frac13. \end{align}